# Ways of expressing "consistent"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english

Im Englischen ist das Wort "consistent" sehr flexibel, aber im Deutschen scheint es mir, dass es mehr Feinheiten gibt, und dass direkte Übersetzungen einfach nicht gehen. Ich gebe einige Beispiele an:

1. > We need to edit the film so that it is consistent (makes logical sense).

   Kann man hier *folgerichtig* benutzen?
2. > We need to make sure that her story is consistent. (No contradictions).

Ich verstehe, dass es in diesem Zusammenhang um "keine Widersprüche" oder "nicht widersprüchlich" geht. Mir wurde aber erzählt, dass sich "konsistent" nur auf die Festigkeit eines Materials bezieht. Hier bin ich wirklich verwirrt.

Comment: Die Frage, wie sie in der Überschrift vorgestellt wird, wirkt sehr allgemein. Wie sie dann ausformuliert ist, macht dann klar, dass es eigentlich um einen spezfischen Sprachgebrauch in der Film- und Medienbranche geht. Insofern hoffe ich, dass sich jemand als Antworter findet, der in diesem Bereich tätigt ist und den derzeit gängigen Usus erläutern kann.

Comment: "konsistent", "in sich schlüssig"? Wer immer behauptet hat, daß [konsistent](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/konsistent) nur im Zusammenhang mit der Beschaffenheit von Materialen verwendet werden kann, hatte unrecht.

Comment: Für das zweite Beispiel gäbe es auch _»widerspruchsfrei«_.

Comment: Mir ist noch kein Fall untergekommen, in dem man *'consistent'* nicht mit *"konsistent"* perfekt übersetzen konnte.  Alle unten beschriebenen Feinheiten im Deutschen gibt es meines Erachtens auch im Englischen.

Answer (score 6):

Aus dem [Online-Duden](https://www.duden.de/):

```
konsistent
 1. a. fest [zusammenhängend]
    b. (z. B. in Form, Aufbau) von festem Zusammenhalt; in sich stabil, beständig
 2. (besonders Logik) zusammenhängend in der Gedankenführung
```

und

```
Konsistenz
1. a. (besonders Fachsprache) Grad und Art des Zusammenhalts eines Stoffes
   b. (bildungssprachlich) konsistente Beschaffenheit
2. (besonders Logik) strenger gedanklicher Zusammenhang
```

Auch [Linguee](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=konsistent) und [Leo](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/consistent) weisen "konsistent" und "consistent" jeweils als mögliche Übersetzungen aus.

---

In den von Dir angeführten Fällen würde ich

> We need to edit the film so that it is consistent.
>
> Wir müssen den Film so schneiden, dass er konsistent ist.

und

> We need to make sure that her story in consistent.
>
> Wir müssen sicherstellen, dass ihre Geschichte konsistent ist.

nicht als falsch empfinden.

Als mögliche Alternative würde ich noch vorschlagen:

> We need to edit the film so that it is consistent.
>
> Wir müssen den Film so schneiden, dass er in sich schlüssig ist.

---

Ich mag mich irren, aber meiner Meinung nach ist ein Film an sich und ohne Kontext nicht "folgerichtig". Die Ereignisse in dem Film können aber natürlich folgerichtig sein.

Comment: "in sich stimmig" wäre noch eine Alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Soweit ich es verstanden hatte, handelt es sich vor allem um die Handlungsabfolge und dabei um so etwas wie die psychologische Plausibilität, soweit sie sich in den Handlungen der Figuren ausdrückt. Man kann das wohl als *'konsistent'* bezeichnen. Ein ungeschickter Filmschnitt kann Inkonsistenzen hervorrufen, der Film kann aber auch von vornherein so angelegt sein. Hochgradig inkonsistent hieße: bar jeder Logik. Ich würde für '*konsistent*' noch vorschlagen: *ohne logische Widersprüche, ohne Brüche in der Logik*, vielleicht auch *'überzeugend'*. Ein ähnliches Adjektiv wäre *'kohärent'*; das meint aber eher den Zusammenhang, bei einem Film wäre etwa ein Nebeneinanderher verschiedener Handlungsstränge ohne erkennbaren Bezug *'inkohärent'*. *'Konsistent'* heißt für mich darüber hinaus: Es gibt einen Gesamtzusammenhang, ein in sich geschlossenes Bild, eine erkennbare Aussage, einen Einheitlichkeit stiftenden Einsatz der verschiedenen filmischen Mittel.

Answer (score 2):

#### in sich stimmig sein

Gerade im Kontext von Dramaturgie, Drehbuch und Film findet man häufig die Formulierung *in sich stimmig sein* für die Beschreibung einer konsistent logischen Handlung.

Beispiele:

> - Es ist eine Inszenierung, die in sich stimmig ist und das im „Rheingold“ begonnene Konzept konsequent weiterentwickelt hat. <sup>[Der Opernfreund](http://www.deropernfreund.de/oldenburg-12.html)</sup>
> - Dieser relativ einfache Handlungsablauf muss undbedingt in sich stimmig sein und einem roten Faden folgen.<sup>[Storytelling - Ein Leitfaden für den animierten Kurzfilm](https://books.google.de/books?id=dXlhAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA26&ots=2x4A-IGfP6&dq=drehbuch%20%22in%20sich%20stimmig%22&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q=drehbuch%20%22in%20sich%20stimmig%22&f=false)</sup>
> - Wenn man jedoch den ganzen Weg bis dorthin mitgegangen ist, erscheint einem diese Entwicklung in sich stimmig.<sup>[So bekommen Sie Ihr Drehbuch in den Griff](https://books.google.de/books?id=EqVADwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA17&ots=S2ez5l80tz&dq=drehbuch%20%22in%20sich%20stimmig%22&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q=drehbuch%20%22in%20sich%20stimmig%22&f=false)</sup>
> - Damit die Geschichte dramatisch ausgewogen und stimmig ist, sollten sich die beiden zentralen Probleme (inneres und äußeres Problem), die im ersten Akt eingeführt werden, aufeinander beziehen. <sup>[Wikipedia: Spielfilmdramaturgie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spielfilmdramaturgie)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt im Deutschen, und ich schätze in den meisten Sprachen, keine Begriffe oder Bedeutungen die vor bildhafter Sprache, Metaphern oder Begriffen ähnlicher Bedeutung aus anderen Sphären oder Sprachen geschützt sind.

Verwenden kann man, wozu man Lust hat - eventuell muss man erklären, was man meint, wenn der Begriff weitgehend unbekannt ist oder man wird nicht verstanden. Je nach dem, wie man die Vorbildung der Zuhörer- oder der Leserschaft einschätzt wird man damit mehr oder weniger erfolgreich sein.

Eine andere Frage, die sich stellt, ist, ob ein Sprachgebrauch etabliert ist, wenn man davor zurückscheut als kreativ oder gebildet gelten zu können. Für *konsistent* kann man das bejahen; der Sprachgebrauch ist etabliert, allerdings eher in Kreisen vom Bildungsniveau Abitur und aufwärts.

In der Fachsprache von Informatikern, Juristen und Drehbuchautoren ist die Verwendung gang und gäbe und sicher auch in weiteren.